# Trying to delete duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1064

I have a database with about 30 fields. It's a membership website and so people join and create a profile, however many members have created several profiles and used their email each time so I need to remove all of the duplicate profiles that have been created, but keeping the most recent one.

Each profile has a unique ID and so I used the script below which brought up a list of all of the profiles that have been created where the end user had used their email multiple times.

```
select min(id) as lastId, email
    from profiles
   where email in (
              select email 
                from profiles
               group by email
              having count(*) > 1
       )
   group by email;
```

The list looks great, it shows the oldest profile that they created in the list and so when I got to this point I was very happy. I then selected the profiles using the checkbox next to each one and clicked the 'delete' button, then:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

I've tried everything. I'm able to delete an entry in the 'normal' but I need to select all the profiles on the list and get rid of them.

Comment: "I then selected the profiles using the checkbox next to each one and clicked the 'delete' button"

What delete button?  In your app?

Comment: It seems you have mis-tagged your post.  You have tagged it "mysql", but the error message indicates you're using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL/MariaDB you must use multiple-table DELETE syntax.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delete/

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM profiles t1
JOIN profiles t2 USING (email)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id;
```

I.e. "delete a row if there exists a row with the same `email` but lower `id`".

Comment: Hi, I have pasted your code into the sql script box and clicked 'ok' Hopefully this will do the trick. UPDATE. The thing timed out and no duplicates have been deleted but everytime I check how many rows (profiles) I have the number is different. It was originally 640000 profile but then I refresh and it shows 854999 then 680666 etc different every time. i hope I havent messed up the databade :-/